# Связанная таблица заполнить и вывод

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Вот мои таблицы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывожу их в `DBGrid` использую `ADOQery`. И у меня возникло два вопроса, как отображать в `DBGrid` вместо `ID_Firma(ключ)` а значение `Name`, так же и для второго. И как правильно добавлять данные? Надо ComboBox для Firma и Name_Kompl и оттуда вынимать ключ. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте что такое lookup-поля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в ADOQuery в запросе сделать JOIN дополнительных таблиц, и в DBGrid.Columns[].FieldName написать соответствующее поле

```
SELECT c.*, f.name, nk.name FROM catalog c 
LEFT JOIN firma f on f.nomer_firma=c.id_firma 
LEFT JOIN name_kompl nk on nk.nomer_kompl=c.id_name_kompl
```